# How do I actually run Apache Felix OSGi's shell?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, gogo-shell

1. I downloaded the current Felix jar linked over from http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi (for version 4.4.1)
2. Extracted the .zip
3. Ran the bin/felix.jar with "java -jar felix.jar"
4. Observed that the felix-cache/ directory was created

I understand that I should be sitting in the Felix shell there, at that point.  But I get no output.  I type "help" as per the instructions here:
http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-usage-documentation.html

But I get nothing in terms of a shell.  Just a blank terminal that lets me type but doesn't respond at all.

Also, as described in the 'remote shell' instructions, I try to 'telnet localhost 6666' and also get nothing.

Am I wrong in terms of what I'm trying to do?  Is the gogo shell a separate application?  If not, and I'm correctly expecting to see the shell, where should I look to further debug this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started felix like this:

```
cd felix-framework-4.4.1/
java -jar bin/felix.jar
```

For me the shell started correctly. So I think what happens for you is that you started from the bin dir and felix looked for the shell bundles in bin/bundle where it obviously could not find any.

See the [felix launcher docs](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html) for more details.

So to answer your second question. Yes the shell is not directly included in felix.jar. It is implemented by the three *gogo bundles in the bundle dir.

Comment: Christian, thank you very much, you nailed it.  I never ran it from the root felix-framework-4.4.1/ directory...always either from the felix-framework-4.4.1/bin directory, or somewhere distant in the filesystem with 'java -jar $HOME/bin/felix-framework-4.4.1/bin/felix.jar'.

Comment: Had the same issue here, thank you! But seriously, why the heck is Linux designed in a way that such a thing matters? >_<

Comment: It is not about linux. The same thing will happen on windows. This is implemented in the felix launcher. It searches the bundles in a subdirectory of the current working dir. See the doc I linked in the answer. You can explicitly tell felix where to look for bundles.

Comment: I just spent 1h trying to figure out what's wrong... this drives me crazy; no errors, nothing, just blocks, go figure out

Comment: Can you post your example project somewhere?

Comment: Jesus, is that you? I guess so, because you're my savior.